# Magento 2.3 addFieldToFilter conditions

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection

I need to filter a collection based on the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ('invoice_state' == 'cancel' AND 'invoice_state_code' == 5) OR ('invoice_state' == 'open' AND 'invoice_state_code' == 1)
```

How can I achieve this using `$collection->addFieldToFilter()` method?